# Is it possible to make all numbers in web-font equal height in css3?

Tags: css, webfonts

I have some webfont with this type of numbers:[image: Railway Bold font]
Does anyone know, is it possible to make all numbers equal height with css features only?

Comment: No...you'd have to use a different font.

Comment: font-feature-settings: "lnum"

Answer (score 0):

Try [font-variant-numeric](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric): lining-nums;
I have no idea if it will work with all fonts. I've only tested with Raleway font.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30895637)